# Store a PHP variable once throughout a webpage.

Tags: php, json

So I have a a variable called json that stores all of the json. I want to load this once in the site, and be able to use it through any php function that I have. So let's say I have this line of code placed at the beginning of index.php:

```
  $json = file_get_contents('http:/xxxxxxxx/bp.json');
```

I want to be able to use this variable from a function somewhere else in the page, WITHOUT loading it again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Use global variables**

```
<?php
$myVar = 1;
function myFunction()
{
    global $myVar;
    $myVar  = 2;
} 

myFunction();
echo $myVar; //will be 2

include 'another.php'; //you can use $myVar in another.php too.
?>
```

[variables PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

**2) Use cookies**

If you want your variable to be access from any browser window or after loading another page, you have to use `COOKIES` since `HTTP` is stateless. These cookies can be accessed via `javascript` since those are stored in client side browser and can be accessed by client.

```
<?php 
setcookie("myVar","myValue",time()+86400);
/*
   86400 is time of cookie expires. (1 day = 86400)
*/
?>


<?php 
/* 
   Getting cookie from anywhere 
*/
$myVar = $_COOKIE["myVar"];
echo $myVar;
?>
```

[cookies PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

**3) Use a session**

Best method to store your variables in server side which is secure than using cookies directly is by using a `HTTP_SESSION`

```
<?php
/* 
   Start a session. 
   Call this line top of every page you want to use session variables 
*/
session_start();
// set variable
$_SESSION["myVar"] = "value";
?>

<?php
session_start();
// Access session variables from another php.
$myVar = $_SESSION["myVar"];
?>
```

[sessions PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: When I'm talking about global, I mean for it to transfer from page to page.

Comment: Doesn't a cookie require `session_start()` to work properly?

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCodes if you want to transfer it from page to page you can user `SESSION` or `COOKIE`. IF you use cookies, those can be accessed via javascript too.

Answer (score 2):

You could store your variables in the PHP session and call it anywhere in your application.

```
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Also best practices is to destroy and/or clear all your session variables upon exiting your application.

Comment: Thank you, quickest and easiest way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way do this ,you can use [Superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

> Superglobals — Superglobals are built-in variables that are always available **in all scopes**

I think you must used supergloabls variables before like $_SERVER,$_GET,$_POST etc,and supergloabls variables also include $GLOBALS.

What is [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

> Note: Variable availability
>   Unlike all of the other superglobals, $GLOBALS has essentially always been available in PHP.

*So you can do this*

1. Get data from json file
2. Assign data to $GLOBALS
3. User $GLOBALS variable instead of $json